# Why custom Rest Error Handler is not getting called when rest template throw exception?

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, custom-error-handling

I am trying to cover all of the rest template calls in my class for exception handling. Using Custom exception handling with error handler in spring boot application.

For this i have created a rest template bean in config and set error handler in it to the custom error handler class that i created with extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler.

```
public class BaseConfig {
@Bean
    @Primary
    RestTemplate restTemplate(@Autowired RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder.errorHandler(new IPSRestErrorHandler()).build();
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class IPSRestErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IPSRestErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (response.getStatusCode()
                .series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR) {
            LOGGER.error("Server error with exception code  : "+response.getStatusCode()+" with message : "+response.getStatusText());
            throw ExceptionUtils.newRunTimeException("Server error with exception code  : "+response.getStatusCode()+" with message : "+response.getStatusText());
        } else if (response.getStatusCode()
                .series() == HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR) {
            LOGGER.error("Client error with exception code  : "+response.getStatusCode()+" with message : "+response.getStatusText());
            throw ExceptionUtils.newRunTimeException("Client error with exception code  : "+response.getStatusCode()+" with message : "+response.getStatusText());
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Unknown HttpStatusCode with exception code  : "+response.getStatusCode()+" with message : "+response.getStatusText());
            throw ExceptionUtils.newRunTimeException("Unknown HttpStatusCode with exception code  : "+response.getStatusCode()+" with message :"+response.getStatusText());
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ServicingPlatformSteps {

 @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

 private ResponseEntity callServicingPlatformAPI(RemittanceV2Input inputClass) {
ResponseEntity entity = null;
entity = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(),
                    org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, typeRef);
return entity;
}
```

Here i am expecting that when restTemplate.exchange method is called and it throws some exception then my IPSRestErrorHandler should be called. But error handler is not getting called. While i am getting this restTemplate instance with error handler info in it.

Could you please help me why error handler is not getting called?

Answer (score 0):

In your case replace below

```
@Component
public class IPSRestErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {

}
```

with

```
@Component
public class IPSRestErrorHandler extends ResponseErrorHandler {

}
```

Please see, `ResponseErrorHandler` will ensure that the `HTTP status` from the `response` is read. So we have to `extend` the same.

And you already have injected the `IPSRestErrorHandler` implementation into the `RestTemplate` instance.

You can read more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling) , it explains how you can unit test also.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate `BaseConfig` with `Contiguration`.
Also, see if you have another config class prividing Bean of `RestTemplate`.